# Why does my Hashmap<Boolean,String> only have two entries?

Tags: java, hashmap

I used a HashMap to store a dictionary of type boolean and the indexName value. However I noticed my hashmap only goes up to 2 in size. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
  public Map<Boolean, String> findMetadata(String scanPackage) {
    Map<Boolean, String> metadatas = new HashMap<>();
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = createComponentScanner();
    for (BeanDefinition beanDef : provider.findCandidateComponents(scanPackage)) {
      try {
        Class<?> cl = Class.forName(beanDef.getBeanClassName());
        Indexable indexable = cl.getAnnotation(Indexable.class);
        logger.info("---------------------------- " + indexable.dictionary() + " " + indexable.indexName());
        if (!metadatas.containsValue(indexable.indexName())) {
          metadatas.put(indexable.dictionary(), indexable.indexName());
        }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error(ERROR + e);
      }
    }
    return metadatas;
  }
```

Comment: you have mentioned that dictionary() is of type boolean. Since, a boolean can take only two valuesd, true and false, its very logical that your hashmap can have max of two values only. If you check the keys of your map, it will have true and false only.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc please read beyond the title of the question before deciding it's a duplicate.

Comment: @akshayapandey actually, that hashmap could has 3 values. true, false and null

Comment: @mdolata yes hashmap can have three values(true,false,null), i am only assuming the value for dictionary() is already initialised, hence have said two

Comment: @akshayapandey with that assumption it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the map declaration in this way:

```
Map<String, Boolean> metadatas = new HashMap<>();
```

and the metadata put in this way:

```
metadatas.put(indexable.indexName(), indexable.dictionary());
```

Maybe this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Map<Boolean,String>` where the key are `Boolean` and the value `String`.

Now, [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) doesn't supports duplicated keys.

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

So you will be limited with the key, since `Boolean` can only have 3 values `true`, `false` and `null`... and since [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) allows `null` key

> This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key

Your maxmimum size will be 3.

Comment: Map is only interface. There is a map implementation which supports key duplicates. It is called IdentityHashMap and check reference equality. So, you could have few "True" keys in that map

Comment: @mdolata `Map` is an interface that provide a contract. The quote provided came directly from that contract (the javadoc). And your class violates the rules and specified it "_This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required._".

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious, you are using Boolean as a key in a hashmap.
Now for Hashmap, below is true.
1. It should have unique keys(Otherwise, It will override the existing value stored corresponding to a key).
and
2. Boolean can have two values either true or false(Can't be null),
so there are only two values in your Map.

If you Want to have a dictionary, you should modify your MAP as below.

```
Map<Integer, String> metadatas = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Index: Should be some numbers, So keys are Integer.
Values should be String.